# PHP: Create read only file without chmod()

Tags: php, chmod

I have chmod() disabled on my server, but I still want users to be able to create read-only files via PHP, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, since it's impossible to put anything in a read-only file...

**EDIT**  actually, there is a way:

```
<?php
  $u = umask(0377); // disables --wxrwxrwx permissions
  $f = fopen("test", "w");
  umask($u);
  fwrite($f, "this is a test\n");
  fclose($f);
?>

% php foo.php
% ls -l test
-r--------  1 xxx xxx  14 19 May 10:27 test
% cat test
this is a test
```

The [`umask`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) manipulation allows you to create a read/write file descriptor, even though the underlying directory entry is read-only.

Comment: to anyone except Alnitak: If your mind is having a hard time understaining the umask value (like mine did), remember that the permission bits files are created with is the inverse of the umask (and removing the execution bits after the inversion). So with that umask, newly created files would be 0400 (or -r-------- if you prefer that way).

Answer (score 0):

As workaround, you could first store the files using [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents), and then use [`ftp_chmod()`](http://php.net/ftp_chmod) to change the file permissions.

The other option would be via the commandline, but if `chmod` is disabled then `exec` is unlikely to work either. And if your hoster disabled both, then there likely is a reason for that. (If only it is to reduce support costs.)